# Display json content in php table

Tags: php, html, json, html-table, slim

I am trying to display json content in php table but I'm getting error every time. I have some syntax error and cant figure out what should i change?

PS. Trying built it with Slim framework

Here is my code:

```
<div class="data-table-wrapper">
<?php
    $myData = file_get_contents("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current.json");
    $myObject = json_decode($myData);
?>
    <table class="data-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Time</td>
                <td>Round</td>
                <td>Circuit</td>
                <td>Location</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?PHP
        foreach($myObject as $key=>$item);
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?PHP echo $item->Date; ?></td>
            <td><?PHP echo $item->Time; ?></td>
            <td><?PHP echo $item->Round; ?></td>
            <td><?PHP echo $item->Circuit; ?></td>
            <td><?PHP echo $item->Location; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?PHP
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

My error is:

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Date in C:\xampp\htdocs\challenge\app\view\challenge.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Time in C:\xampp\htdocs\challenge\app\view\challenge.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Round in C:\xampp\htdocs\challenge\app\view\challenge.php on line 40

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Circuit in C:\xampp\htdocs\challenge\app\view\challenge.php on line 41

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just looked at your `json` format in comparison to the code. The path mapping to the `json` is incorrect. I have rectified that below;

Please review the following:

**PHP code**:

```
$myData = file_get_contents("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current.json");
$myObject = json_decode($myData);
$myObjectMap = $myObject->MRData->RaceTable->Races;
```

**For each format**:

```
  <?php foreach($myObjectMap as $key => $item): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->date; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->time; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->round; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->Circuit->circuitId; ?></td>
      <td><?PHP echo $item->Circuit->Location->country; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Full Code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    $myData = file_get_contents("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current.json");
    $myObject = json_decode($myData);
    $myObjectMap = $myObject->MRData->RaceTable->Races;
  ?>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Round</td>
        <td>Circuit</td>
        <td>Location</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach($myObjectMap as $key => $item): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?PHP echo $item->date; ?></td>
          <td><?PHP echo $item->time; ?></td>
          <td><?PHP echo $item->round; ?></td>
          <td><?PHP echo $item->Circuit->circuitId; ?></td>
          <td><?PHP echo $item->Circuit->Location->country; ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that decoded array looks differently. Dump your encoded array before the loop to understand the right data structure or use [JSON beautify service](http://jsbeautifier.org/). Also use the right upper/lowercase to address properties. Updated loop may look like this:

```
<div class="data-table-wrapper">
<?php
$myData = file_get_contents("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current.json");
$myObject = json_decode($myData);

?>
   <table class="data-table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>Date</td>
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>Round</td>
      <td>Circuit</td>
      <td>Location</td>
    </tr>
    <?PHP
    foreach($myObject->MRData->RaceTable->Races as $key=>$item){
    ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?PHP echo $item->date; ?></td>
    <td><?PHP echo $item->time; ?></td>
    <td><?PHP echo $item->round; ?></td>
    <td><?PHP echo $item->Circuit->circuitName; ?></td>
    <td><?PHP echo $item->Circuit->Location->locality; ?></td>
  </tr>
 <?PHP
   }
 ?>
   </table>
       </div>
        </div>
```